# How to: Pandas division of columns when multiindex present due to pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sales dataset which I read into a Pandas dataframe and pivoted to group information.  Now columns are a Multiindex and looks like this:

```
MultiIndex([('Orders', 'Pants'),
        ('Orders', 'Shirts'),
        ('Orders', 'Shoes'),
        ( 'Spend', 'Pants'),
        ( 'Spend', 'Shirts'),
        ( 'Spend', 'Shoes'),,
       names=[None, 'Product'])
```

Now, I am trying to calculate an "average order value" for each "product".  I want to do something like:

```
# Calculate Avg. Order Value by dividing Spend Series by Orders Series
dataframe['AOV'] = dataframe['Spend'] / dataframe['Orders']
```

But I cannot.  How do I end up with a dataframe that has these column multiindex:

```
MultiIndex([('Orders', 'Pants'),
            ('Orders', 'Shirts'),
            ('Orders', 'Shoes'),
            ( 'Spend', 'Pants'),
            ( 'Spend', 'Shirts'),
            ( 'Spend', 'Shoes'),
            ( 'AOV', 'Pants'),
            ( 'AOV', 'Shirts'),
            ( 'AOV', 'Shoes'),
           names=[None, 'Product'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide `Spend` by `Orders` then `concat` with `keys` parameter to append additional index level called `AOV` then `concat` with the original dataframe to get the result

```
AOV = pd.concat([df.loc['Spend'] / df.loc['Orders']], keys=['AOV'])
result = pd.concat([df, AOV])
```

Alternatively you can `unstack` the dataframe then divide and stack back

```
s = df.unstack()
s.loc['AOV'] = s.loc['Spend'] / s.loc['Orders']
result = s.stack()
```